# Drop and then create same columns in current up migration function

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, migration

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropTimestamps();
            $table->dropColumn(['email', 'bio']);

            $table->string('email', 20)->unique()->after('id');
            $table->string('bio', 150)->after('surname');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

That is what I've got now. So, I have the columns existing atm in my table, but I want to modify and re-arrange them a bit. But when I run the migration, I get SQL error that `email` column exists. And I will probably get the same error for the `bio` and `timestamps` as well. I kind of understand why this happens, so what am I asking is just for a workaround.

Is it possible to make what I want inside one single migration, or I have to create a migration for deleting the columns and then a separate migration for creating them the way I want?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just break the schema up into two calls

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropTimestamps();
        $table->dropColumn(['email', 'bio']);
    });

    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('email', 20)->unique()->after('id');
        $table->string('bio', 150)->after('surname');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

This way the change is occurring in one *migration* with two database calls.

Comment: This solution fixes their issue but is a potentially unsafe solution because it results in data loss. You should change the columns instead of dropping them.

Comment: @Oranges13 - the title of the question is "Drop and then create columns" - so it is exactly what the OP asked for.

Comment: perhaps, but sometimes new developers ask the wrong questions. A Jr. dev in my company led me to this question because they said it was the solution they found when googling, and I wanted to make sure that no one else gets into an issue where they potentially lose data. Which is why I proposed an alternate solution and provided justification for why you don't want to drop in all cases.

Comment: thank you, I didn't know that I have to create a separate Schema for dropping and creating. I also can't remember any notes about this in Laravel Docs.

Answer (score 2):

Consider that if you drop the columns, you will lose ALL THE DATA contained therein. Normally this is a very bad and dangerous idea. If you instead need to simply change parameters, you should use the `change()` function to make the required modifications to your schema. This will convert the existing data to the best of your databases's ability.

NEVER DROP COLUMNS on an in-use database unless you absolutely know what you're doing.

```php
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // Add the unique constraint, for example
            $table->string('email', 20)->unique()->after('id')->change();
            // Add the length to the bio, for example
            $table->string('bio', 150)->after('surname')->change();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // Remove length and constraints
            $table->string('email')->unique(false)->change();
            $table->string('bio')->change();
        });
    }
```